# How to remove " " from each column

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a CSV file containing the fields like

```
     input.csv
    "1","12","3"
    "4","2","6"
    "8","10","9"
    "9","9","12"
    "10","8","18"
    "12","10","27"
```

I want to remove the "" from each column which gives the output as

```
output.csv
    1,12,3
    4,2,6
    8,10,9
    9,9,12
    10,8,18
    12,10,27
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sed 's/\"//g' file`. Should do the trick

To apply the changes on the same file use `sed -i`
To create a new file use `> newfile` at the end of the command.